# Worship God via Image – is one passage sufficient?

Tags: scripture, gods, worship

It is said that the below quote confirms that one has to worship the image – also see a link to the question [Is there anywhere in the scriptures where it say we should worship God through an Idol?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/48540/25502)

Gita 9.26: Whoever makes an offering to Me with devotion, be it of leaf, flower, fruit or water - that devout offering made by a pure-hearted man, I accept with joy.

I'm not sure that the above confirms worship via image/idol, but if we accept this.

Question – can ONE passage from all the books be sufficient for it to be accepted that images can be worshipped or worshiped via images/idols?

Comment: The quote that you have given is in Gita 9.26 and not in Shiva Purana.

Comment: The worshiper visualizes the Formless Devi Parama ShivA in Form and adores Her in the linga, sign-symbol, altar, Fire, Water, winnowing fan, wall, image/idol , Mandala (diagram), plank, in the head or in the heart. These ten places are known to be the different places of worship.  --- the above verses quoted in the answer (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38789/4732) show that scriptures permit deity worship in various Adharas (object of worship) like image, idol, Yantra etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are many passages in Hindu scripture that praise murti puja.

> Henceforth, **I shall mention the benefit accruing from the installation
> of the idol entirely, for the welfare of the world.** The idol may be in
> accordance with one’s own wish.

**Linga Purana I.76.1**

Image worship and love of humans

> I abide in all beings as their inner-most soul. Disregarding My
> presence within them, men make a show of worshiping Me through images.
> If one disregards Me present in all as their soul and Lord but
> ignorantly offers worship only to images, such worship is as
> ineffective as a sacrificial offering made in ashes. A man who
> persecutes Me residing in others, who is proud and haughty, who looks
> upon God as the other – such a person will never attain to peace of
> mind. If a man disregards and persecutes fellow beings, but worships
> Me in images with numerous rituals and rich offerings, I am not at all
> pleased with him for proffering such worship. **A man should, however,
> worship Me in images,** side by side with discharging his duties, which
> include the love of all beings, until he actually realises My presence
> in in himself and in all beings. As long as man is self-centred and
> makes an absolute distinction between himself and others (without
> recognising the unity of all in Me, the Inner Pervader), he will be
> subject to the great fear of Death (including every form of
> deprivation of self-interest). So, overcoming the separateness of a
> self-centred life, one should serve all beings with gifts, honour and
> love, recognising that such service is really being rendered to Me who
> reside in all beings as their innermost soul.

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.29.21-27**

> Till the realisation of perfect knowledge a man should continue the
> ritualistic worship of Shiva. In order to convince the world,
> the rituals must be continued.
>
> Just as the sun is reflected in many vessels, in the same manner, O
> devas, know that the supreme Brahman, Shiva, assumes the form of
> whatever is seen or heard in the world real or unreal. There is
> difference in vessels but not in the water they contain.
>
> This is what those who know the real meaning of the Vedas say. "Lord
> Shiva is within the heart of beings in this world." Of what avail are
> images to those who have the real knowledge?
>
> **Having an image is very auspicious for a person who has no such
> knowledge. It is a ladder that enables him to climb to a higher
> position.**
>
> **It is very difficult to climb to a position without a support. The
> image is only a means to achieve the Nirguna Shiva.**
>
> **The attainment of the Nirguna through a Saguna is certainly possible.
> In this manner, the symbols of all lords are conductive to steady
> faith and belief.**
>
> **This lord is very great and this is the mode of worship of that lord.
> If there is no image, of what avail are scents, sandal paste, flowers
> etc?**
>
> **Till the realisation of true knowledge, the image shall necessarily be
> worshipped. If any one does not worship the image before he attains
> perfect knowledge, his downfall is sure.**

**Shiva Purana, Rudra Samhita, Section I, Creation, Chapter 12**

> In every figure he hath been the mode; this is his only form for us to
> look on. Indra moves multiform by his illusions; for his Bay Steeds
> are yoked, ten times a hundred.

**Rig Veda VI.47.18**

Basic elements of Murti or Pratima Puja is there in the Rig Veda itself. The idea that a Devata can enter every figure and has many forms allows one to do Murti puja.

Comment: Thank you, if I have miss quoted in the question can you correct/edit he question -  as that is what I thought you mentioned in the other question in the link.  is there any more passages you can quote.